# Welder rewiring

Tags: wiring, welding

The wires of the incoming cable pulled out of my old oil cooled welder. I need to reconnect the live and neutral but there is no indication on the welder where either should  go. Does it matter? I'd appreciate any help to get going again. I'm in South Africa, running on 220V.[image][image]

Comment: In the US, on 240v appliances, it doesn't matter which screw the two hot wires go to - they are interchangeable.  If there are no markings or different colored screws, that _might_ be the case, but I'm not familiar with your electric system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two long for a comment: 
It looks like that brand is sold in South Africa and I could not find that model. You know how long your wires were there should be some metal fittings where the wires were and that there is no paint. Is South Africa on 240v or 120v from the small gauge of the wiring I would guess it’s a 240v and your brown would be your hot and blue neutral unless it is split phase as Jphil1618 mentions then both would be hots.
 If one of your connection points also connects ground or the frame that would be the blue if there is no connection it probably not matter as a welder is a transformer ac doesn’t care But you don’t want to energize the frame. If one of the connection points ends up at a switch that would be your brown or hot. That’s all I can think of since I could not find your specific model.